# A list of all supported Android views?

Tags: android, android-view

Is there an up to date link that includes all Android Views. I couldn't find such a page on [Android Developers Website](http://developer.android.com). I don't want to leave it up to chance to know about new Layouts, Widgets etc.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary.html

Comment: Since you can always write a custom view, there's infinite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`android.widget` package documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary.html) contains a list of all of the classes in the `android.widget`, which is where the vast majority of View classes reside.

Some Views belong to the [`android.support.v4.widget`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/package-summary.html) and [`android.support.v7.widget`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/package-summary.html) packages as well.

However I think you are overestimating how frequently new Views are added to these packages. Typically the SDK is updated about once a year, and major new additions to Views aren't going to be kept a secret. Traditionally new API additions are outlined in an API page such as [this one for API 19 / Android 4.4](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html), and a link to the updates along with a brief summary of new versions will also be posted to the [official Android developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/).

Comment: thanks a lot. I was hoping to find a website that keeps track of all android views without having to look for multiple resources.

Comment: I would add [android.support.design.widget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/package-summary.html) as well since it includes the FloatingActionButton as well, for example.

Answer (score 3):

You could always browse through [the actual git repository source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/) if you want the most bleeding edge access to the Android API.

The widgets can be found currently under ["android-4.4.3_r1/core/java/android/widget"](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4.3_r1/core/java/android/widget/), and the core Java API for 4.4.3 is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4.3_r1/core/java/android/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. these links are definitely useful. unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to vote you up

Answer (score 0):

Look at the **Classes** section here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary.html

Each class, when clicked, will reveal the API level in which it was introduced and/or deprecated.